# Convert Linear Multistep Method into one-step method

Tags: numerical-methods

When given an nth-order ordinary differential equation, it is possible to make a simple algebraic manipulation to convert the differential equation into a first-order "autonomous" differential equation. Is there a similar transformation from a linear multistep method into a one-step method or is this in general not possible? For example, consider

$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} \left( f(y_n) + f(y_{n+1}) \right)$.

We can "convert" this into an explicit method by

$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} \left( f(y_n) + f(y_n + hf(y_n)) \right)$.

This makes the method go from two-step into one-step (and in fact, converts it from implicit to explicit). Can this be generalized?

Comment: This will not work in general as a multistep method (apart from the order 1 and 2 examples that are identical to one-step methods) has a memory over multiple time steps while in a one-step method the information reduces to the state at one time between one step and the next.

Comment: I believe the transformation I provide in the answer is correct. The one-step method that I provide as a motivating example...but that scheme is not equivalent to the implicit one. As for memory...when you pass to a vector, each element in the difference scheme now represents more data.

Comment: But what would the Butcher-tableau of that method be? What is the abstract one-step method that this is a specialization of?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following construction works.Consider $s$-step linear multistep method

\begin{align*}
y_{n+s} = a_{s-1}y_{n+s-1} + ...+a_0y_{n}+h(b_{s}f(y_{n+s})+...+b_0f(y_n)).
\end{align*}

Define

\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{s-1}       & a_{s-2} & ... & a_{0} \\
    1       & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & ... & 0 \\
    .   \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{s}       & b_{s-1} & ... & b_{0} \\
    0       & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    .   \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
z_n = \begin{bmatrix}
    y_{n+s-1} \\
    . \\
    . \\
    . \\
    y_n 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
F(z_n) = \begin{bmatrix}
    f(y_{n+s-1}) \\
    . \\
    . \\
    . \\
    f(y_n) 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

The multistep method now reads
\begin{align*}
z_{n+1} = A z_n + h B F(z_n).
\end{align*}
This is a one-step method.